# Skip ahead during playback with keyboard shortcuts

Tags: 10.04, shortcut-keys, rhythmbox

I'm running Rhythmbox under Ubuntu 10.04.  I am looking for a way to map a keyboard shortcut to advancing a track by a specified amount of time, say 20-30 seconds.

The goal is to be able to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NextTrackKey</kbd> and skip embedded ads in podcasts. I'm using Rhythmbox but am willing to change to Banshee if that would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a small plugin for that; [Rhythmbox Skip Ahead](https://github.com/downloads/emj/Skip-ahead-plugin/Rhythmbox-Skip.tgz), you are free to [improve the source](https://github.com/emj/Skip-ahead-plugin) if you want. ATM the skip is hardcoded to 20 seconds and the shortcut is `Ctrl-v`. Just Extract the tarball and run install.sh, please.

A possible future feature would be to automatically skip the first 20 seconds of certain podcasts, but that's advanced stuff..

Or you can use the `pythonconsole`plugin and run the [`skip_ahead` function](https://github.com/emj/Skip-ahead-plugin/blob/c0e813b2a28ad450d1629e8a9ecc0e550fa2bf3e/__init__.py#L27)

Comment: Hey thanks.  That at least is a big step forward towards what I need.